# Entity Framework code first extra columns

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure, ef-code-first, azure-mobile-services

I have been out of C# and development for a while so bear with me.

Have an entity class `List` as below:

```
public class List : EntityData
{
    public int ListId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual List<ListItem> ListItems { get; set; }
}
```

But the corresponding table that is created uses this DDL with extra columns.  Why?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Lists] 
(
    [Id]        NVARCHAR (128)     DEFAULT (newid()) NOT NULL,
    [ListId]    INT                NOT NULL,
    [Name]      NVARCHAR (MAX)     NULL,
    [UserId]    NVARCHAR (MAX)     NULL,
    [Version]   ROWVERSION         NOT NULL,
    [CreatedAt] DATETIMEOFFSET (7) DEFAULT (sysutcdatetime()) NOT NULL,
    [UpdatedAt] DATETIMEOFFSET (7) NULL,
    [Deleted]   BIT                NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Lists] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

Comment: Show us the `EntityData` class

Answer (score 3):

They aren't extra, but are defined by [`Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.EntityData`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt587298.aspx).

Those extra fields serve the purpose of

> An abstract implementation of the ITableData interface indicating how the system properties for a given table data model are to be serialized when communicating with clients when using Entity Framework for accessing the backend store. The uniform serialization of system properties ensures that the clients can process the system properties uniformly across platforms. Concrete entity framework models can derive from this base class in order to support the system properties.

Answer (score 0):

Your base class 'EntityData' either implemented ITableData interface or it has its own properties similar like ITableData.
So your code EntityData class look like this

```
public class EntityData : ITableData
{
    public DateTimeOffset? CreatedAt { get; set; }

    public bool Deleted { get; set; }

    public string Id { get; set; }

    public DateTimeOffset? UpdatedAt { get; set; }

    public byte[] Version { get; set; }
}
```

You won't get extra columns when you remove inhering base class(EntityData) from List model class.